# Tascam dr40x 'stereo mode' with built0in mics yields doubled/strange audio

Tags: microphone, stereo, portable-recorder, tascam

I have a Tascam Dr40x.

I have mainly the default settings, recording as mp3 192.

When I record in 'stereo record mode' with the built in mics I am getting this weird 'doubled voice' sound. However, when I use the 'dual mode' (which is also stereo, it seems), it sounds fine.

What am I doing wrong/what am I misunderstanding? Thanks!